# Fill div with user selected image on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, image-uploading

I have a simple `HTML` page with 4 `buttons` and 4 `divs` positioned as shown below -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.top {
    position: relative;
    left: 205px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
} 

div.left {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
div.right {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 205px;
    left: 410px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
div.bottom {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 205px;
    left: 205px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>

<button type="button">Image 1</button>
<button type="button">Image 2</button>
<button type="button">Image 3</button>
<button type="button">Image 4</button>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to allow the user to be able to select a particular image from the file browser, when a button is clicked, and display the same in the corresponding `div`. For eg. When the user clicks `Image 1`, a file browser should ask him to chose an image, which after being selected, will show in the particular div. I want the user to be able to do this for all the 4 divs and buttons. 
BEen stuck on this for too long, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where is the code for this? What have you tried already?

Comment: I looked up how to allow the user to upload an image, and all the code snippets I saw included building a form. I'm new to HTML, wasn't sure if it was necessary. Hence I posted a question. @Dan White

Comment: A file is just another input type. Even if it is the only field, it is still a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use, although not sure if this will work on you, it might give the idea to follow

```
<input type="file" name="profile_photo" id="fileInput" onchange="loadFile(event)" required>
<div>
    <img class="" id="output"> // This is where the image will be shown
</div>

<script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          var output = document.getElementById('output');
          output.src = reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Works exactly the way I want it to! Any idea if the same thing should work for videos? @Tesseract

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! @tesseract

Comment: If it doesn't, post another question for that matter

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.top {
    position: relative;
    left: 205px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
} 

div.left {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
div.right {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 205px;
    left: 410px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
div.bottom {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 205px;
    left: 205px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: cursive;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.imgView{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.vedioView{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<h1>Select Image And Display In Div</h1>
<div class="top" id="img1Div">
    <img class="imgView" id="img1DivImg">
</div>
<div class="left" id="img2Div">
    <img class="imgView" id="img2DivImg">
</div>
<div class="right" id="img3Div">
    <img class="imgView" id="img3DivImg">
</div>
<div class="bottom" id="img4Div">
    <img class="imgView" id="img4DivImg">
</div>

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Image 1</span>
    <input type="file" id="img1" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Image 2</span>
    <input type="file" id="img2" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Image 3</span>
    <input type="file" id="img3" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Image 4</span>
    <input type="file" id="img4" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<h1>Select Vedio And Display In Div</h1>
<div class="top" id="vedio1Div">
    <video class="vedioView" id="vedio1DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="left" id="vedio2Div">
    <video class="vedioView" id="vedio2DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="right" id="vedio3Div">
    <video class="vedioView" id="vedio3DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div class="bottom" id="vedio4Div">
    <video class="vedioView" id="vedio4DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Vedio 1</span>
    <input type="file" id="vedio1" class="upload" onchange="setVedioToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Vedio 2</span>
    <input type="file" id="vedio2" class="upload" onchange="setVedioToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Vedio 3</span>
    <input type="file" id="vedio3" class="upload" onchange="setVedioToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Vedio 4</span>
    <input type="file" id="vedio4" class="upload" onchange="setVedioToDiv(this)"/>
</div>
<script>
    var setImageToDiv = function(event) {
        var myVar = event;
        if(myVar.files[0].type.split('/')[0] != "image"){
            alert("Please select Image Only");
        }
        else{
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
                var fUploadID = myVar.getAttribute('id');
                var imageSrc = document.getElementById(fUploadID + 'DivImg');
                imageSrc.src = reader.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);
        }
    };
    var setVedioToDiv = function(event) {
        var myVar = event;
        if(myVar.files[0].type.split('/')[0] != "video"){
            alert("Please select video Only");
        }
        else{
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
                var fUploadID = myVar.getAttribute('id');
                var imageSrc = document.getElementById(fUploadID + 'DivVedio');
                imageSrc.src = reader.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);
        }
    };
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try this code, may answer your question with specific your Requirement.

Comment: Just tried it, thank you for putting up an efficient one!

Comment: Could you please let me know if the same thing could work for videos? @kinjal Akhani

Comment: @KinjalAkhani You could instead combine your codes into 1 answer, or at least put some label of some sort

Comment: Try this code, in this i have combine logic to Select Image and Video with 2 different portion and if User Upload file other then Image in case of Image Section then alert message would be displayed and same thing applied to Video also. May this will satisfied your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```js
var setImageToDiv = function(event) {
  myVar = event;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var fUploadID = myVar.getAttribute('id');
    var imageSrc = document.getElementById(fUploadID + 'DivVedio');
    imageSrc.src = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);
};
```

```css
div.top {
  position: relative;
  left: 205px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

div.left {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

div.right {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 205px;
  left: 410px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

div.bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 205px;
  left: 205px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.vedioView {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top" id="vedio1Div">
  <video class="vedioView" id="vedio1DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
<div class="left" id="vedio2Div">
  <video class="vedioView" id="vedio2DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
<div class="right" id="vedio3Div">
  <video class="vedioView" id="vedio3DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
<div class="bottom" id="vedio4Div">
  <video class="vedioView" id="vedio4DivVedio" width="320" height="240" controls> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
  <span>Vedio 1</span>
  <input type="file" id="vedio1" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)" />
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
  <span>Vedio 2</span>
  <input type="file" id="vedio2" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)" />
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
  <span>Vedio 3</span>
  <input type="file" id="vedio3" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)" />
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
  <span>Vedio 4</span>
  <input type="file" id="vedio4" class="upload" onchange="setImageToDiv(this)" />
</div>
```

Comment: @TheLuminor - Please check the above modified code for Displaying Vedios instead of Images.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kinjal Akhani I am currently away from my terminal but I will try it out as soon as i can and let you know! Thank you!